# How to get device market model in Android Studio

Tags: android

I need the market model, like Samsung S10e, on a TextView.

```
String reqString = Build.MANUFACTURER
    + " " + Build.MODEL + " " + Build.VERSION.RELEASE
    + " " + Build.VERSION_CODES.class.getFields()[android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT].getName();
textView.setText(reqString);
```

Comment: See [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59881536/how-can-i-get-the-processor-model-and-brand)

Answer (score 0):

**You can use below code -**

```
    public static String getDeviceName() {
  String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
  String model = Build.MODEL;
  if (model.startsWith(manufacturer)) {
    return capitalize(model);
  }
  return capitalize(manufacturer) + " " + model;
}

private static String capitalize(String str) {
  if (TextUtils.isEmpty(str)) {
    return str;
  }
  char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
  boolean capitalizeNext = true;

  StringBuilder phrase = new StringBuilder();
  for (char c : arr) {
    if (capitalizeNext && Character.isLetter(c)) {
      phrase.append(Character.toUpperCase(c));
      capitalizeNext = false;
      continue;
    } else if (Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
      capitalizeNext = true;
    }
    phrase.append(c);
  }

  return phrase.toString();
}
```

You can use below library for getting device details -

[library](https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidDeviceNames)

Comment: Hi, thanks, I used you code and I got nothing on the app. What do you mean when you say that I can use the library?

Comment: I did add the library, but it doesn´t show nothing on the app, do I have to add the Text View?

Comment: yes on text view it will show textView.setText(getDeviceName());

Comment: When I try yo use the textView, it donesn´t work, it says tha it´s because it´s static

Comment: I think now I´m doing it ok, but on the app it shows "Samsung SM-6970F" instead of "Samsung S10e"